# Arduino USB Keyboard - Send the Fn (Function key) in code

Tags: c, arduino

I am new to the Arduino coding. I am building a small device with buttons that send key presses to the computer. This will be done by emulating a USB keyboard via Teensy 2.0 and Arduino.

Can anyone help me (or is it possible) to send a Fn (Function)key press using Arduino? I haven't been able to find anything online anywhere.

Comment: Google the "PS/2" protocol.  That might get you pointed in the right directions.  It's a byte level protocol that encodes keyboard keys into a known value for transmission from the keyboard to the computer.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have spent a tremendous amount of time on the pjrc.com site looking at code. I have my base code right now and it works great. I just need to know if it's possible to send a Fn (Function) modifier.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The Fn key is handled internally by the keyboard. It is never sent to the computer. See [this explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key#Technical_details).